# How to debug PHP script when it is being accessed by android application

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have an Android application that is connectiont to a web server running MySQL DB. On the web server I have `php` files that run scripts and return `JSON` Objects to the client (application). I recently upgraded the versions of my web server and as of then, the `SELECT` statements are no longer returning anything to the client if they have parameteres, however if I run a `SELECT` with no parameters, it works fine. Has anyone ever encountered a similar problem?

To be more clear about my question:

**Is there anyway I can debug**`php` **scripts?**

I thought maybe debugging via a web browser wouldn't work because the client is triggering the php files directly and not a direct access to the web.

All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has a set of tools that let you remote debug from your android.

Check them out:  https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: You can only debug javascript like that.

Comment: @matthijs You can do a lot with JavaScript if you add some scripting to debug your remote calls.

Comment: You are correct, however i assume that's not where he is looking for

Answer (score 0):

You could wirte your own error handler an let him wirting some debug informations to a own log-file. than you can read the log file and check it for errors

Answer (score 0):

1. Look at the MySQL error log and the php error log on your server
2. Check you activated the correct php_mysql* extensions in the newly upgraded PHP
3. Run the scripts on the server through a browser with the same parameters that your app uses, watch for errors
4. Upgrade the PHP code running on the server so it captures any errors and does something OBVIOUS with them.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use XDEBUG for debugging PHP code, or any analogue for yours web server. It is really simple to set-up and use it with any PHP IDE ([like Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html)) and it gives you a lot of abilities to explore your application condition. There is no difference in what browser you will open link with ?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug parameter.

Also you can watch MySQL and Web-server logs.

If you cannot do anything above and you need to watch network action (AJAX requests), you can set-up [ADB](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) and use chrome developer console for debugging js (or to see php var_dump() in ajax calls) in you android chrome browser.

If you need to debug js in native android browser - try to redirect to "about:debug" page, and after this you will be able to see browsers js console (in some cases this button appears only when console has something to show - error or any othe message, in some cases it just doesn't work).

Update Watch Duplicate Copy Move

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, you can debug using the error logs given by `mysql` and `php`. There are also **IDE**s which come with debugging tools for scripting languages like `php`.

With an IDE like [phpStorm by JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/), which I highly recommend using over just a normal text editor, you can configure **data sources** like a connection to your `MySQL` db. This is useful because you can run scripts in the IDE and see whether it's the retreival of the data from your db or something in your scripts or handling of the `JSON` object back in the client. So if you configure a data source and run those same scripts and you get the correct data back then you know there is either something wrong in the code where you send the data or something wrong in the code where you receive it.

***p.s. I know that I am 5 years (oh my days its been 5 years since 2013) late to this post but none the less you never know who may be having this same issue and they stumble accross this answer*

Answer (score 0):

1st - Setup Xdebug for remote debugging with your IDE(Eclipse, PHPStrom, etc), and put breakpoints in your script.(for example here's [link](https://jonathansblog.co.uk/remote-debugging-php-in-eclipse-with-xdebug) for setting up eclipse envirompment).

2-nd - When sending your url request to server add parametres to your url(http://your/url.php&***XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGP&KEY=XXXXX,***

-1st parameter -  **XDEBUG_SESSION_START**=ECLIPSE_DBGP  starts debugging session. (as for  me  I am using eclipse IDE for developing, so my key will be ECLIPSE_DBGP).

-2nd parameter - **KEY**=XXXXXX - is a session number(type any number here).

After that you'll get your code breaks at your debugging point in your script.